# Can I leave a garden hose under pressure for long periods of time?

Tags: water-pressure

Is it okay to leave the water pressure on using a garden hose and turn the water off by just the sprinkle nozzle? My water faucet is difficult to get to.

Comment: do you care more about the hose or the convenience?

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly OK to turn off the water at the end of a hose for short periods. If you leave it on this way for long periods you are stressing the hose which could lead to a ruptured hose when you are not around. This could lead to a waste  of water or to water damage if the hose sprays on something.

In addition, this could lead to a leaking water valve because the stem packing will be under pressure. The usual valves have a seal around the rotating (multi-turn) stem, but if the valve is a "ball valve" (90 deg on-off), then this doesn't apply.

I think it is best practice to shut off the valve on the pipe when you are finished using the water.

Comment: I agree prior to plumbing our outter pasture's we had several hundred feet of hoses going to water troughs with floats. our irrigation system is way to large and has silt in the water, the hoses worked for several years except for winter freezes, the only hoses we lost were because horses or the tractor punctured in 1 place but it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider it a good idea for several reasons. A quality hose will normally contain the pressure from the supply be it a well or municipal supply. If the hose in in direct sunlight the pressure can increase to the bursting point. If you have a back flow preventer included in or added to your spigot the pressure will increase rapidly.  If you don't have an anti backflow device you could push the water from the hose back into your house plumbing.

Comment: Since liquids expand only negligibly (0.00012 per degree F), why would the hose burst?

Comment: @isherwood multiply that number by 100, for a 100F temperature rise if the hose is in full sunlight, and you have about a 1% change in length. Try stretching an 8 foot length of hose pipe to make it an inch longer, and see how much force you need to do that! Have you ever had a copper water pipe burst when the water inside froze?

Comment: Where are you *ever* going to see a 100 degree temperature rise in a hose? That would really be something. Plus, you seem to be assuming zero change in diameter, so....

Comment: I don't know much about anti-backflow devices, but I think if a home is being used (i.e. someone is usually home, hello wfh 2020) then the excess pressure can find its way out of the system once anyone uses any water.

Comment: However, I can definitely imagine a "hose" whose material was that of a normal balloon would definitely have trouble. Imagine putting a balloon onto the end of a hose. Ok. It's most definitely going to fill up, fall off the hose, or if it's on the ground, burst. Might be fun to watch.

Comment: If the strength of your hose under the unrelenting summer sunshine/heat is questionable, then yes, turn spigot off. (Likely, you bought a nice hose that is not a hefty POS). If you bought the hefty POS, congratulations. Probably not going to burst. If you have a shitty sprayer, well, maybe it'll break, you'll waste a bunch of money on water, and buy a better sprayer nozzle.